# Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

Error: Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG

I used the following steps/commands to run my testNG script through command prompt:

```
1. in my project folder, create a lib folder and copy all the jar files
2. open cmd --> cd myProjectDirectoryPath
3. set classpath=myProjectDirectoryPath/bin
4. set classpath=myProjectDirectoryPath/lib/*
5. java org.testNG.TestNG testng.xml
```

but after that i am getting Could not find or load main class org.testng.TestNG
error. tried to debug but still not successful. can someone help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try at least to add to `classpath`:

```
set classpath=myProjectDirectoryPath/bin
set classpath=%classpath%;myProjectDirectoryPath/lib/*
```

If not, the second "`set`" override the first.

Of specify the cp (classpath) directly ni the java command:

```
java -cp myProjectDirectoryPath/bin;myProjectDirectoryPath/lib/* org.testng.TestNG testng.xml
```

In both instance, make sure you have a `testng.jar` in one of those folders.